# How to Display String on Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to display first 5 characters, but in my code it displays from end:

```
module TEST_gate;
reg[8*5:1]str1;
initial begin 
str1="HelloWorld";
$display("str1= %s",str1);
```

I want to display `Hello` but it displays `World`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `reg` is not wide enough to hold all 10 characters of your string.  To store all characters, change:

```
reg[8*5:1]str1;
```

to:

```
reg[8*10:1]str1;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.9 *String literals*.

> A string literal can be assigned to an integral type, such as a packed
> array. If the size differs, it is right justified. To fully store a
> string literal, the integral type should be declared with a width
> equal to the number of characters in the string multiplied by 8.

Then you need to select a range according to the 1st 5 characters for your display.

If you enable SystemVerilog features in your simulator, you can use the `string` data type instead:

```
module tb;

reg[8*10:1]str1;
string str2;

initial begin 
    str1="HelloWorld";
    str2="HelloWorld";
    $display("str1= %s",str1);
    $display("str1= %s",str1[80:41]);
    $display("str2= %s",str2);
    $display("str2= %s",str2.substr(0,4));
end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
str1= HelloWorld
str1= Hello
str2= HelloWorld
str2= Hello
```

Refer to section 6.16.8 *Substr()*.

Answer (score 1):

In Verilog, string literals are just packed arrays of bits (or a bit-vector), each character is 8 ASCII bits. The left most bit of the first character in a string is the MSB of the vector and the right most bit of the last character is the LSB of the vector.

Your "HelloWorld" string literal is 10 characters repressing an 80-bit packed array and you are trying to assign it to a 40 bit variable. With any assignment from a larger to smaller integral variable, Verilog right justifies and silently truncates the bits to the left, in your case the bits representing "Hello".